# Is there a WYSIWYG editor that will render inline, and linked stylesheets during editing?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-2010, wysiwyg

**Disclaimer: This question is not about fixing visual studio**

---

So, I've used VSS for so long to edit HTML source that I actuall completely forgot there was a design view button. So for fun I clicked it.  When I clicked it here is what I got.

[image]

Now,  I fully expected it to look like crap since my styles are defined in separate css files.  This got me wondering.  Has there ever been a WYSIWYG editor that will render a page while editing using all stylesheets even external ones?

Comment: Every WYSIWYG editor that I've ever used has supported external style sheets. They're not necessarily a new invention. I'm surprised that VS doesn't. Have you tried anything else that doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that [WebPutty](https://web.archive.org/web/20130329170234/http://www.webputty.net:80/) would help. You embed a WebPutty script on your site and it allows you to edit your CSS real-time and publish to your site as well right from WebPutty. It's not as powerful as Coda but does the trick if all you're concerned about is adjusting your CSS.

Comment: That's pretty amazing.  I really like that it minifies and gzips too.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out [Coda](https://panic.com/coda/) and [Espresso](https://espressoapp.com/) - both of these editors render external stylesheets in the design view when editing html. They also have beautiful interfaces and embedded ftp clients : )

Comment: Only caveat is that they work poorly on Windows :-) Otherwise, yes, I'm a huge fan of Coda.

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver. *cough

The design view is usually pretty close, but sometimes chokes for no apparent reason.

Comment: I kinda like dreamweaver. I don't use the design view at all. but I like the functionality of the program overall. However, lately I have become partial to netbeans, No design view there.